# How can I add emoji matching into this JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, emoji

I have a working regex to match letters, numbers, punctuation in JavaScript:

`var letters = /^[0-9A-Za-z\s\-_@#$*!&'’‘”“"?,.:/=+<>~%^ ]+$/;`

I want to add emojis to this. How can I modify the regex to match emoji as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by adding the Unicode representation of the emoji set into the regex (using sets of independent Unicode ranges), as follows:

`var letters = /^([0-9A-Za-z\s_@#$*!&'’‘”“"?,.:\/=+<>~%^ \u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}\u{1f680}-\u{1f6ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}\u{1f1e6}-\u{1f1ff}\u{1f191}-\u{1f251}\u{1f004}\u{1f0cf}\u{1f170}-\u{1f171}\u{1f17e}-\u{1f17f}\u{1f18e}\u{3030}\u{2b50}\u{2b55}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2b05}-\u{2b07}\u{2b1b}-\u{2b1c}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{303d}\u{00a9}\u{00ae}\u{2122}\u{23f3}\u{24c2}\u{23e9}-\u{23ef}\u{25b6}\u{23f8}-\u{23fa}-]+)$/gu;`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.